# react @types conflicts with typescript dom types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-typescript

Is there a way to specifically import types from typescript dom and not from react? Types from react seem to not be correct.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error you get is unrelated to React/TypeScript's conflicting names.

Comment: how come? it imports/uses the `HTMLIFrameElement` from react(which is just a `HTMLElement`) and not from lib.dom.d.ts

Comment: Well the first hint would be that the error message mentions nothing about `HTMLIFrameElement`...

Comment: it's not seen in the screenshot, but the element is cast to `HTMLIFrameElement `